# Making a module in Playframework

Tags: module, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Playframework 1.2.4 and I have created a project that I would like to turn into a module since I am using this class in many projects. This class is just called TJUser, there you create and delete users among other things.

I created an empty project
     play new testproject
Then I created a module inside the project
    cd testproject
    play new-module user

Then I copied my user class and views into user/app/controller/user and my views into user/app/vies/user and the same with models.
I also copied over the routes file from the project and placed that in user/conf

The project I made works. But I can't get my module to run. I don't know the next steps.

Hope someone can assist

Comment: check out the blog post, but you are missing the step at least where your main applications routes file needs to point at your module's routes file to pick up the routes...they are not picked up automatically, in case of conflict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about using modules. http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/play-modules/

Hopefully it can help you with your question.